# VSCode から Java の実行時、class ファイルが生成されないのはなぜ？

Tags: java, vscode

vscodeでjavaをコンパイルするとclassファイルが作られぬまま実行されます。

vscode上でclassファイルを生成する方法はないのでしょうか？

また、classファイルが生成されないのに実行できるのはなぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ビルドツール](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build)を利用していないアンマネージドフォルダタイプの Java プロジェクトの場合、
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> でコマンドパレットを開き **Java: Configure Classpath** と入力するとクラスパス設定画面が開きます。

この設定画面の **Output** 設定値が `.class` ファイルの出力先になります。

変更可能ですが、変更した場合はコマンドパレットから **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace** を実行しないと反映されないことがあります。

[image: VSCode Java class file output]

参考:

- [Managing Java Projects in VS Code > Configure classpath for unmanaged folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-classpath-for-unmanaged-folders)

Comment: ちなみにビルドツールを用いている場合はそのビルドツールの(明示的/暗黙的)設定に従います。(が、これは自明なので質問者の期待する回答ではないと判断しました)

Answer (score 1):

私の環境の場合ですが、格納場所は見つけることができましたので記述します。

classファイルは以下のパスにありました。
`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\hogehogehoge\redhat.java\jdt_ws\hogehogehoge\bin`

`hogehogehoge`は任意のフォルダ名です。

Answer (score 0):

VSCodeでの実行方法にもよりますが、おそらく`javac`ではなく、`java`コマンドを使用していると思います。

`java`だとclassファイルを生成しないで、実行だけしてくれます。

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld.java
```