# 「クラスにmain(String[])メソッドが見つかりません: Student」と出て結果が出ません

Tags: java

windowsでvscodeを使用しています。Javaで作ったのですが、ターミナルでjava Student.javaと入力しても「クラスにmain(String[])メソッドが見つかりません: Student」と出て結果が出ません。どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

```
class Student{
    String name = "satou";

    public void calculateAvg(int math,int english){
        System.out.println((math + english)/2);
    }
}

class Lesson13_01{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student a001 = new Student();
        a001.name = "satou";

        System.out.println(a001.name);
        a001.calculateAvg(90,80);
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問者以外の人の編集によって、文意が変わっている可能性があるように感じました。 `Student` クラスと `Lesson13_01` クラスは同一ファイル(`Student.java`)で定義されている前提で回答が付いていますが、元々の質問文では必ずしもそうとは限らないように見えます。

Comment: なので、ファイル名とそのファイルの内容が対応付くよう、質問者自身に質問文を更新してもらえるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ターミナルでjava Student.javaと入力しても「クラスにmain(String[])メソッドが見つかりません: Student」と出て結果が出ません。

エラーメッセージのとおり、クラスにmainメソッドが見つかっていません。
Student.javaにはmainメソッドを定義したクラスをソースファイルの先頭にかけば実行するエラーは解消されます。

### Student.java

```java
class Lesson13_01{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student a001 = new Student();
        a001.name = "satou";

        System.out.println(a001.name);
        a001.calculateAvg(90,80);
    }
}

class Student{
    String name = "satou";

    public void calculateAvg(int math,int english){
        System.out.println((math + english)/2);
    }
}
```

```
java Student.java
satou
85
```

ツール・リファレンスの[ソース・ファイル・モードで単一ファイルのソース・コードのプログラムを起動する方法](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__USINGSOURCE-FILEMODETOLAUNCHSINGLE--B5E57618)によると

> ソース・ファイル・モードでは、ソース・ファイルがメモリーにコンパイルされた場合と同様に、ソース・ファイル内で最初に検出されたクラスが実行されます。

とあります。

---

ソース・ファイル・モードはJava 11から導入されたようです。
ソース・ファイル・モードはちょっとしたコードを試してみるとき非常に便利ですが、本格的なJavaのプログラムを書くときはJavacで明示的にコンパイルして実行することをお勧めします。

---

Javaソースのファイル名はクラス名.javaとするのが一般的です。

動作確認に使用したJavaのバージョンは以下です。

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

VSCode の GUI で Run(実行) ボタンを押して実行するのに相当するコマンドラインは

```
javac -d classes *.java
java -cp classes Lesson13_01
```

です。

関連:

- [Javaプログラムがターミナルから実行できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/54441/2808)
- [VSCode から Java の実行時、class ファイルが生成されないのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/84058/2808)

  - 前述コマンドラインでは `classes` ディレクトリに`.class`ファイルが生成されますが、VSCode上で実行した場合にはVSCodeが定めた別の場所に生成されています

---

質問文中のコードを見た感じ、何か入門書などを参考にされているように見えます。

入門書ではあまり質問文に書かれているようなやり方(`Lesson13_01` クラスと `Student` を同一ファイルに書き下したり、コンパイルせずに `java` コマンドで直接実行したり)はしないと思うので、もし何か参考にされているのであれば、説明を理解し間違えている可能性があるかと考えます。

Comment: 参考: 質問内のコードはこちらの記事に見られるようです https://kino-code.com/course-java13-class/

Answer (score 1):

実行のさせ方が違います。`javac` コマンドでプログラムをバイトコードにし、`java` コマンドで実行させてください。

手元だと以下で実行できました。

```sh
javac Student.java
java Lesson13_01
```